# How many $8$-digit numbers do not contain the string $55555$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

I'm having a little trouble figuring out this exercise.

Consider an $8$-digit number. How many numbers do not contain even numbers? How many numbers do not contain the string $55555$?

For the first part I've worked out that since there are only $5$ odd numbers $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ and a total of $8$ digits the answer is $5^8$, but I don't know how to tackle the second part.

Comment: what do you mean by ```not contains 55555```

Comment: The string 55555 can't be a part of the end resut

Comment: then separate cases the number of  5s < 5 and if it contains > 5 then add gaps

Comment: Do you mean an $8$-digit positive integer or an $8$-digit decimal string, meaning that the first digit is permitted to be $0$?

Comment: Thanks to N.F. Taussig for finding a flaw in my analysis.  I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** 
First see (all) of the comments following this answer, especially the comments of N.F. Taussig.  I overlooked a required subtlety of my approach.  I have edited my answer accordingly.

Further, since this subtlety is required by my approach, it is **now** unclear to me whether Inclusion-Exclusion is more appropriate.

---

The computation is $T - F$ where $T$ is the total number of 8 digit numbers possible and $F$ is the total number of 8 digit numbers possible that contain "$55555$".

This problem has two wrinkles:

- Can the leftmost digit = $0$?
- Should [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) be used.

I will start with the arbitrary interpretation that the leftmost digit can be $0$.  Then, at the end of my answer, I will adjust, in case this interpretation is outlawed.  Although Inclusion-Exclusion is plausible, simplest approach (**edit: ??**) is to stay with mutually exclusive cases.

$$T = 10^{8}.$$

To compute $F$, I will compute $F_5, F_6, F_7,$ and $F_8$, where $F_k$ denotes how many 8 digit numbers have exactly $k$ $5$'s and have a block of "$55555$".

Then, $$F = F_5 + F_6 + F_7 + F_8.$$

Clearly, $$F_8 = 1.$$

For $F_7$, the gapped digit may not be the 4th or 5th digit (from the left), since the block of "$55555$" must occur.  Therefore,

$$F_7 = 6 \times 10^1.$$

**Edit**
The above computation for $F_7$ is wrong, since it overlooks that $F_7$ represents having **exactly** seven $5$'s.  The correct computation here is

$$F_7 = 6 \times 9^1.$$

For $F_6$, the following locations of the non-5 digits are permissible: 
$\{(1,2), (1,3), (1,7), (1,8), (2,3), (2,8), (6,7), (6,8), (7,8)\}$

Therefore,

$$F_6 = 9 \times 10^2.$$

**Edit**
The above computation for $F_6$ is wrong, since it overlooks that $F_6$ represents having **exactly** six $5$'s.  The correct computation here is

$$F_6 = 9 \times 9^2.$$

For $F_5$, the string of "$55555$" must begin on digit positions $1,2,3$ or $4$.

Therefore,

$$F_5 = 4 \times 10^3.$$

**Edit**
The above computation for $F_5$ is wrong, since it overlooks that $F_5$ represents having **exactly** five $5$'s.  The correct computation here is

$$F_5 = 4 \times 9^3.$$

---

If leftmost digit can not be $0$:

**Edit**
In this section, I apply all of the editing needed, without elaboration, re $F_k$ represents the situation where **exactly** $k$ $5$'s are present.

The first adjustment is

$$T = 9 \times 10^7.$$

For $F_8$, no adjustment is necessary.

For $F_7$, if the gapped digit is the 1st digit from the left, then there are only 8 choices for the 1st digit (i.e. the first digit can not be a $0$ or a $5$).  If instead, the gapped digit is any of digit positions $2,3,6,7,8$, then in each case, there are 9 possible digits for the gapped position.

Therefore $$F_7 = 8 + (5 \times 9) = 53.$$

For $F_6$, of the 9 permissible locations for the non-5 digits, 4 of the 9 involved the 1st digit.  When the first digit is involved, there are only ($8 \times 9 = 72$) possibilities, instead of ($9^2$).

Therefore, $$F_6 = (4 \times 72) + (5 \times 81).$$

For $F_5$, if the leftmost digit occurs in the 1st slot, the enumeration of $(9^3)$ stands.  If it begins in the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th slot, then the enumeration becomes $8 \times 9^2.$

Therefore $$F_5 = 729 + (3 \times 648).$$

Comment: Your answer is not correct.  Notice that a string which contains six consecutive $5$s contains two $55555$ strings, a string  which contains seven consecutive $5$s contains three $55555$ strings, and a string which contains eight consecutive $5$s contains four $55555$ strings.  You should be using Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig When someone with your proven ability on mathSE comments, I have to pay very close attention.  However, it is still unclear to me whether I have made a mistake.  I define $F_k$ to be the mutually exclusive situation of exactly $k$ 5's occurring, that contain a string of at least 5 consecutive 5's.  Double checking, $F_7$ does have 6 permissible locations for the non-5 digit, $F_6$ does have 9 permissible locations for the two non-5 digits, and $F_5$ does have 4 permissible locations for the start of the block of "55555".  In my mutually exclusive scenarios, what am I overlooking?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I certainly agree that the problem is routinely solvable via Inclusion-Exclusion.  However, this (in and of itself) does not imply that my analysis is faulty.  Further, if my analysis is not faulty, then one has to question which approach can be more easily understood by the OP.  I opted for my approach because it was easier for **me** to understand.

Comment: According to your analysis for the case of eight-digit decimal strings, $F = 4961$, so $T - F = 99,995,039$.  Using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, I get $99,996,300$.

Comment: Focusing on eight-digit decimal strings, one error I see in your analysis is your count of $F_7$.  You observe correctly that there must be a $5$ in the fourth of fifth position, giving you six choices for the position of the digit which is not a $5$.  However, if the other digit is not a $5$, it can only be selected in $9$ ways, not $10$.   You made the same error in calculating $F_6$ and $F_5$.  Replacing $10$ by $9$ in each step gives $F = 3700$.  Notice that $10^8 - 3700 = 99,996,300$, as I found.  Your analysis can be made to work, but I still recommend Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig +1 Very good catch.  I will edit my answer accordingly, referring to your comments both re the mistake and the alternative approach.  Further, having been blind to the required subtlety in my approach, this calls into question whether Inclusion-Exclusion is better.

Answer (score 2):

If $55555$ appears as a (consecutive) substring, its earliest appearance begins with one of the first four digits. If that earliest appearance begins with the first digit, then the final three digits can be anything. If it begins with the second, third, or fourth digit, then the digit immediately preceding it cannot be a $5$ but can be anything else, and the remaining two digits, wherever they are, can be anything. Thus the total numbero of eight-digit strings containing $55555$ is

$$10^3+3(9\cdot10^2)=3700$$

so the number of eight-digit strings *without* $55555$ as a substring is

$$10^8-3700$$

Comment: +1 embarrassingly elegant